# Eclipse CDT build output to bin/Release and bin/Debug

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

How could I configure Eclipse to put the output of a build (Release or Debug) in `bin/Release` or `bin/Debug`? I would like to avoid putting those files directly into the project root Release or Debug directory.

I am using GNU Make Builder with an external build type and generate the makefile automatically by eclipse. I guess it is the default c++ project configuration.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse's internal builder, a Makefile or something else?

Comment: Please have a look at my edit. (Builder: GNU Make Builder, Build type: external, Makefile: automatically).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately neither the Eclipse managed GNU Make Builder tool chain or the internal builder supports setting alternative build locations. There is a long running issue asking for this kind of functionality here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=180451

The Autotools tool chain does have support for setting the build location. Though it fills the project root directory with all the Autotools files and may be too much of heavy weight solution.

That leaves you looking for other options if you want that kind of control.
You could consider:

- Manually manage you own GNU Makefile.
- Switch to CMake.

Comment: That's really painful, as expected - Eclipse. I decided to create an own makefile. Thanks.